# jquery raty and jquery ui map adding stars to the infowindow dynamically based on data from getJson()

Tags: jquery, google-maps, dom, getjson, jquery-ui-map

I have a problem with proper configuration off dynamically adding of ratings to the info window of jquery ui map.

**First** I tried to do it in on the go in $.each of getJson like that:

```
$(labelka).raty({ readOnly: true,  score: marker.friendly_rate});
```

where labelka was before set to: `var labelka = "#spot"+marker.id`
where marker.id is value of id from row from getJson, and friendly_rate is numerical value apporpriatlly.

Result: NO SUCCESS:

**Second try:** I thought, before you refere to something it has to exist. So wait until jqxhr=getJson finsh. So in getJson() I only append to the gloably visible dictionary key:values as follows:

```
pair_mark[labelka]=marker.friendly_rate
```

And then inside of `jqxhr.complete(function() {} I trie to do

jqxhr.complete(function() {

```
for (var key in pair_mark){
    $("#map_canvas").find(key).raty({ readOnly: true,  half  : true, score: pair_mark[key] });
}
  console.log( "second complete" );
});`
```

also: NO SUCCESS

even while trying:

```
$(key).raty({ readOnly: true,  half  : true, score: pair_mark[key] })
```

Screenshot of Google Chrom console [(BIGGER RESOLUTION)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzto3.jpg):
[image]

And link to source code:
https://gist.github.com/andilab/2efe76bb1ffbeeaa26ee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

```
 var labelka = "#spot"+marker.id
 var html_part ="<div id=\""+labelka+"\"></div>";
```

this will create the following markup:

```
<div id="#spotSomeMarkerId"></div>
```

This node may not be selected in jQuery by using `$('#spotSomeMarkerId');` , because the # must be ommitted in the id-attribute of the `<div/>`.

The basic problem: The content of the InfoWindow is provided as string, the DOM for this content will be available when the domready-event of the InfoWindow fires, not before. You can't call `$.raty()` for the paricular InfoWindow before that.

Possible solutions:

- as mentioned, wait until  the domready-event fires
- use a DOM-Node as content for the InfoWindow, in that case you may call raty as soon as you have created the DOM-Node(no matter if the Node has already been injected into the document/the InfoWindow is open)

---

code for the 2nd approach(use it as replacement for the lines 121-123 of your gist):

```
var contencik = $('<div><h4>'+marker.name+'</h4><br>'
                    + marker.address_street
                    + ' '+marker.address_number
                    + '<br>Rating:</div>')
                  //the content is ready, it's a query-object
                  //now we append-the raty-container and call raty immediately
                  //for this container
                  .append($('<div id="spot'+marker.id+'"></div>')
                            .raty({ readOnly: true, score: marker.friendly_rate}))
                  //the content is still a jQuery-object
                  //we need a DOM-node to pass it to the 
                  //content-property of the InfoWindow
                  [0];
```

Comment: The Issue with hash I have noticed. But still it does not work. The second one mentioned I am going to test.

Comment: What you mean by `domready-event fires`? You mean: `jqxhr.complete(function()` ?

Comment: Could you explain it more precise ` DOM-Node as content for the InfoWindow` I am newbie to jQuery. THANK YOU for Your help.

Comment: The content-property of an InfoWindow may either be a string(with HTML-markup, as you currently use it) or some element(e.g. a div, h4 ... elements are so-called DOMNodes). With `domready` I mean the the domready-event of the InfoWindow, it fires as soon as the content of a InfoWindow has been injected into the document(usually immediately before the InfoWindow will be opened). I've added a possible fix above.